# Overwrite if already exist My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile (vb.net)

Tags: vb.net

I got this code, works like a charm! But how can I make it so it overwrites if it already exists? Thanks!

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If FolderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        Dim URL As String = "https://finncoding.com/assets/styles/app.css"
        Dim SaveFile As String = "app.css"

        With FolderBrowserDialog1
            TextBox1.Text = .SelectedPath
            My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile(URL, IO.Path.Combine(.SelectedPath, SaveFile))
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: check if the file exists, if yes, delete it and save new file

Comment: @PeterKsenak But how to do that in code, that's what I need to know.

Comment: sorry Imma not free writing code service, try to do on your own.. it is trivial thing.. google for : how to check if the file exists vb net, how to save file in vb net, how to delete file in vb net.. thanks for understanding

Comment: @MarkusDev98 [How to: Delete a File in Visual Basic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/developing-apps/programming/drives-directories-files/how-to-delete-a-file).

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so here's how I solve this one. I go to [the documentation of My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.devices.network.downloadfile?view=netframework-4.8) and I read the help for the version of the method that you're calling; the one with two strings. It has a Remarks section that says:

> If the destination file already exists, the DownloadFile method will not overwrite the existing file. You can use one of the other overloads of the DownloadFile method to instruct it to overwrite existing files, provide user credentials, or specify a specific timeout value.

So I carry on looking in the documentation at the other versions of this same method and I see there is one:

```
DownloadFile (address As String, destinationFileName As String, userName As String, password As String, showUI As Boolean, connectionTimeout As Integer, overwrite As Boolean)
```

So I wonder "I only really need address, destinationFilename and overwrite, what should I put for the other parameters?" The documentation gives default values for the other stuff so that's a good starting point :

address String
Path of the file to download, including file name and host address.

```
destinationFileName String
File name and path of the downloaded file.

userName String
User name to authenticate. Default is an empty string, "".

password String
Password to authenticate. Default is an empty string, "".

showUI Boolean
True to display the progress of the operation; otherwise False. Default is False.

connectionTimeout Int32
Timeout interval, in milliseconds. Default is 100 seconds.

overwrite Boolean
True to overwrite existing files; otherwise False. Default is False.
```

Hence I can say you can just change your code so it calls:

```
My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile(URL, IO.Path.Combine(.SelectedPath, SaveFile), "", "", False, 100000, True)
                                                                                                       ^^^^
```

It's the final True that is overwrite. I'll leave you to decide whether you want to change any other stuff like whether to show a UI giving the download progress. Hopefully the most important thing you take away from this is not the single line of code that is the answer but a tip on how to better use documentation to help get answers to your problems faster than having to laboriously write out a question here and wait hours for a few characters solution

Comment: *the documentation typically uses c# syntax* :) In the upper band of almost all the Msdn Docs pages, related to .Net classes, there 's the Language selector (it's also a persistent preference).

Comment: @jimi I guess me being a majority C# guy explains that one, then. There used to be selectors above every code box, and I never  knew up to now where the option had disappeared to. Thanks for the tip